# On first load getting 403 error on server. How can I fix it

Tags: .net-core

On local its working fine but when I publish on server on first load it throws 403 error in console and if I refresh error is gone

Comment: Please take the time to clarify your post by including 1) what exactly it is you are doing, 2) your question, and 3) any code that is relevant to the question.  As is, it's impossible to answer your post.